# Documentation for Serializing Contract Call Data/Parameters

Tags: smart-contracts, transactions, wallets, encoding

Is there any documentation available for how to serialize contract call parameters?

I found good documentation for serialization of general [operations](https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/p2p.html#entrypoint-determined-from-data-8-bit-tag) and took a look at the [tzips](https://gitlab.com/tzip/tzip) but neither seems to explain how to create a contract call from scratch *without* relying on external services for serialization of the parameters. Language for the implementation in this case is C#.

Any help/links is appreciated :-)

Comment: This might be helpful: https://www.ocamlpro.com/2018/11/15/an-introduction-to-tezos-rpcs-a-basic-wallet/ they use JSON, but the approach is similar for binary, you just need to use the binary encoding instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is https://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/micheline.html#binary-serialization which mostly tells to run `tezos-codec describe alpha.script.expr binary schema` for a complete description of the binary encoding.

More details are given [here](https://medium.com/the-cryptonomic-aperiodical/the-magic-and-mystery-of-the-micheline-binary-format-33bf85699bef).

Comment: Do I see it correctly that in order to write a general purpose contract call software, I would have to write 1.) Michelson => Micheline compiler and 2.) Micheline => binary encoder?
This seems like quite the Hercules task.

Comment: Michelson and Micheline are not two separate languages, Micheline is Michelson's concrete syntax.

Comment: Thanks!
Any easy way to get the FA2 interface definitions found at [tzip-12](https://gitlab.com/tzip/tzip/-/blob/master/proposals/tzip-12/tzip-12.md) in Micheline instead of Michelson?
For FA1.2 I found existing transactions from which I could extract the micheline signature.

Comment: Do you mean JSON?

Comment: Exactly, the equivalent of the "JSON RPC View" of https://tzkt.io/op6iMF4mjKmdvdSgwDjZNkVYTD1BzWnU1tKeCYKih82AKc6zM3i e.g. which looks to be in micheline

Comment: So you want to convert from Micheline to JSON, this can be done using `tezos-client convert data ... from Michelson to Json`.